# Getting SSL working locally with Rails on OSX for development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, ssl

I'm' trying to get SLL working locally with Rails 4.2.5 on El Capitan with thin (I don't really care if it's thin or not though), and I tried several things, most recently this: https://gist.github.com/trcarden/3295935 (also pasted below)-- but it's not working.

```
# SSL self signed localhost for rails start to finish, no red warnings. 

# 1) Create your private key (any password will do, we remove it below)

$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.orig.key 2048


# 2) Remove the password

$ openssl rsa -in server.orig.key -out server.key


# 3) Generate the csr (Certificate signing request) (Details are important!)

$ openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr

# IMPORTANT
# MUST have localhost.ssl as the common name to keep browsers happy 
# (has to do with non internal domain names ... which sadly can be
# avoided with a domain name with a "." in the middle of it somewhere)

Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:
...
Common Name: localhost.ssl 
...


# 4) Generate self signed ssl certificate 

$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt

# 5) Finally Add localhost.ssl to your hosts file

$ echo "127.0.0.1 localhost.ssl" | sudo tee -a /private/etc/hosts

# 6) Boot thin

$ thin start --ssl --ssl-verify --ssl-key-file server.key --ssl-cert-file server.crt

# 7) Add server.crt as trusted !!SYSTEM!! (not login) cert in the mac osx keychain
# Open keychain tool, drag .crt file to system, and trust everything.

# Notes:
# 1) Https traffic and http traffic can't be served from the same thin process. If you want 
#    both you need to start two instances on different ports.
#
#
```

I then go to https://localhost.ssl:3001 and the lock in the browser still has the red X.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get it to work in the end?

Answer (score 2):

I did get this to work.

First one of the errors I directly see is that you are trying to connect to port 3001 but the server you start is on port 3000.

Secondly the `--ssl-verify` was not accepted so I removed it.

Also do not forget to add the created certificate to the keychain and change it to trusted.

And finally you need to tell Rails to use the localhost.ssl domain name for assets etc so make sure you have this in `config/environments/development.rb`:

`config.action_controller.asset_host      = 'https://localhost.ssl:3000'`

Note the S on the https.

Comment: Note, this also works with puma. In the puma case, step 6 is not required. Instead, add `ssl_bind '127.0.0.1', '3000', { key: path_to_key, cert: path_to_cert }` to your `config/puma.rb` file. Simply start your server from the command line with `rails s` and you can start handling https requests.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, binding rails in development mode to "localhost" instead of an IP address (such as 0.0.0.0) is treated as a valid SSL origin regardless if you have generated an SSL key/cert. Any deprecation warnings should be quieted when running as localhost.

This is stated here (under "Testing Powerful Features, #2):

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins

Instead of using `rails s` to start Puma/Thin, you would use `rails s -b localhost -p 3000`, and then access your app through `http://localhost:3000`